# Group by relationship and sort by relationship field

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6, eloquent-relationship

I have some models that I need to list in a certain order. I have many `Task` that belong to a `Project`: a `Project` can have many `Task`, and several `Task` can belong to many `Project`.

In my `TaskController@index` I want to list all `Task`, grouped by `Project.id` and `Project.updated_at`. Example:

```
Project 1
- Task 1
- Task 2
- Task 3

Project 2
- Task 1
- Task 2
- Task 3
```

How can I solve this in the most simple way in `TaskController`?

Comment: laravel provides great documentation with straightforward solution for your task, check [link](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries)

Comment: @rebellion did my answer led you on the right track?

Comment: @PhilMarc Not exactly, but I solved it in another way. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The key to your problem is to **extend the relationship with a query function**:
`$this->hasMany('Task')->orderBy('updated_at');`

*Example:*

Your `Project.php` Model:

```
<?php

class Project
{
    public function tasks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Task')->orderBy('updated_at');
    }
}
```

Your `TaskController.php` controller:

```
<?php

class TaskController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $projects = Project::with('tasks')->orderBy('updated_at')->get();

        // Then use $projects in the blade template
        return view('my-projects', compact('projects'));
    }
}
```

Your `projects.blade.php` blade file:

```
@foreach($projects as $project)

<p>{{$project->name}}</p>

<ul>
    @foreach($project->tasks as $task)
    <li>{{$task->name}}</li>
    @endforeach
</ul>

@endforeach
```